# Scraping with python - problem with xpaths

Tags: python, scrapy

A user had helped me on another site but by taking the basic code and adapting it to a new site my code does not work. It doesn't return any result.

The error probably comes from the access paths (xpaths) but I copy/paste when I inspect the site...

the objective is to have a complete database of all active players with their performances.

Then I would like to have them over several years, then the teams to make dataviz.

That's why if you even have resources on xpaths I'm interested :)

Here is the code :

```
import logging
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess


class SoccerSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'soccer'

    start_urls = ["https://sofifa.com"]

    def parse(self, response):
        # list of all the recipes urls on the page
        all_links = response.xpath('//html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/table').getall()
        for link in all_links:
            # request recipe page
            yield scrapy.Request(url=f'https://sofifa.com/{link}', callback=self.parse_recipe)

        # get the url of the next page
        next_page = response.xpath('//div[@class="pagination"]/a/@href')/getall()
        if next_page:
            # the default callback is 'parse'
            yield scrapy.Request(url=self.start_urls[0]+next_page)

    # parse the recipe page
    def parse_recipe(self, response):
        name = response.xpath('//html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/h1/text()').get()
        club = response.xpath('//html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/h5/a/text()').get()
        prix = response.xpath('//html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/section/div[3]/div/text()').get()
        salaire = response.xpath('//html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/section/div[4]/div/text()').get()
        average_score_club = response.xpath('//html/body//div[2]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/ul/li[1]/span/text()').get()
        national_club = response.xpath('//html/body//div[2]/div/div[2]/div[5]/div/h5/a/text()').get()
        average_score_national = response.xpath('//html/body//div[2]/div/div[2]/div[5]/div/ul/li[1]/span/text()').get()
        tag = response.xpath('//html/body//div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/ul/text()').getall()
        attacking = response.xpath ('//html/body//div[3]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/ul/text()').getall()
        skill = response.xpath ('//html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/ul/text()').getall()
        movement = response.xpath ('//html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[5]/div/ul/text()').getall()
        power = response.xpath ('//html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[6]/div/ul/text()').getall()
        mentality = response.xpath ('//html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[7]/div/ul/text()').getall()
        defending = response.xpath ('//html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[8]/div/ul/text()').getall()
        goalkeeping = response.xpath ('//html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[9]/div/ul/text()').getall()
        

        yield {
            'name': name,
            'club': club,
            'price' : price,
            'wage': wage,
            'average_score_club': average_score_club,
            'national_club' : national_club,
            'average_score_national': average_score_national,
            'tag': tag,
            'attacking' : attacking,
            'skill': skill,
            'movement': movement,
            'power' : power,
            'mentality': mentality,
            'defending': defending,
            'goalkeeping' : goalkeeping
        }


# Name of the file where the results will be saved
filename = "soccer_database_3.json"

# Declare a new CrawlerProcess with some settings
process = CrawlerProcess(settings={
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)',
    'LOG_LEVEL': logging.INFO,
    "FEEDS": {
        f'results/{filename}': {"format": "json",
                                'overwrite': True,  # instead of checking if the file exists just overwrite it
                                'encoding': 'utf8'
                                },
    }
})

# Start the crawling using the spider you defined above
process.crawl(SoccerSpider)
process.start()
```

I try an other code but the result is the same ... Here is code :

```
class SoccerSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'soccer'

    start_urls = ["https://sofifa.com"]

    def parse(self, response):
        # list of all the recipes urls on the page
        all_links = response.xpath('//*[@id="body"]/div[1]/div/div[2]/@href').getall()
        for link in all_links:
            # request recipe page
            yield scrapy.Request(url=f'https://sofifa.com/{link}', callback=self.parse_recipe)

        # get the url of the next page
        next_page = response.xpath('//*[@id="body"]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/a/@href')/getall()
        if next_page:
            # the default callback is 'parse'
            yield scrapy.Request(url=self.start_urls[0]+next_page)

    # parse the recipe page
    def parse_recipe(self, response):
        name = response.xpath('//*[@id="body"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/h1/text()').get()
        club = response.xpath('//*[@id="body"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/h5/a/text()').get()
        average_score = response.xpath('//*[@id="body"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/section/div[1]/div/span/text()').get()
        prix = response.xpath('//*[@id="body"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/section/div[3]/div/text()').get()
        salaire = response.xpath('//*[@id="body"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/section/div[4]/div/text()').get()
        national_club = response.xpath('//*[@id="body"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[5]/div/h5/a/text()').get()
        tag = response.xpath('//*[@id="body"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/ul/text()').getall()
        attacking = response.xpath ('//*[@id="body"]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/ul/text()').getall()
        skill = response.xpath ('//*[@id="body"]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/ul/text()').getall()
        movement = response.xpath ('//*[@id="body"]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[5]/div/ul/text()').getall()
        power = response.xpath ('//*[@id="body"]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[6]/div/ul/text()').getall()
        mentality = response.xpath ('//*[@id="body"]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[7]/div/ul/text()').getall()
        defending = response.xpath ('//*[@id="body"]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[8]/div/ul/text()').getall()
        goalkeeping = response.xpath ('//*[@id="body"]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[9]/div/ul/text()').getall()
        

        yield {
            'name': name,
            'club': club,
            'price' : price,
            'wage': wage,
            'average_score_club': average_score_club,
            'national_club' : national_club,
            'average_score_national': average_score_national,
            'tag': tag,
            'attacking' : attacking,
            'skill': skill,
            'movement': movement,
            'power' : power,
            'mentality': mentality,
            'defending': defending,
            'goalkeeping' : goalkeeping
        }
```

The output of the code is :

```
2022-03-10 15:32:58 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.5.1 started (bot: scrapybot)
2022-03-10 15:32:58 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.6.1.0, libxml2 2.9.10, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 21.7.0, Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  4 2020, 02:22:02) - [Clang 10.0.0 ], pyOpenSSL 19.1.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1h  22 Sep 2020), cryptography 3.1.1, Platform macOS-10.16-x86_64-i386-64bit
2022-03-10 15:32:58 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'LOG_LEVEL': 20,
 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'}
2022-03-10 15:32:58 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: d38a333a0d9a3de3
2022-03-10 15:32:58 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2022-03-10 15:32:58 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2022-03-10 15:32:58 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2022-03-10 15:32:58 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2022-03-10 15:32:58 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2022-03-10 15:32:58 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-03-10 15:32:58 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2022-03-10 15:32:59 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://sofifa.com> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 120, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/utils/python.py", line 353, in __next__
    return next(self.data)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/utils/python.py", line 353, in __next__
    return next(self.data)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 56, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/offsite.py", line 29, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 56, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/referer.py", line 342, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 56, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/urllength.py", line 40, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 56, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 56, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "<ipython-input-2-ce9c6b4f502c>", line 14, in parse
    next_page = response.xpath('//*[@id="body"]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/a/@href')/getall()
NameError: name 'getall' is not defined
2022-03-10 15:32:59 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2022-03-10 15:32:59 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 230,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 92949,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 0.399734,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 10, 14, 32, 59, 347866),
 'httpcompression/response_bytes': 493316,
 'httpcompression/response_count': 1,
 'log_count/ERROR': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'memusage/max': 75173888,
 'memusage/startup': 75173888,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'spider_exceptions/NameError': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 10, 14, 32, 58, 948132)}
2022-03-10 15:32:59 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

After executing code, my json doc is empty
[Doc image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRz2l.png)

Thank for your help
Have a good day

Comment: You should give some information about what happens when you run the code. Please add the logger output too.

Comment: Thank you tomjn I add an other informations and output

Comment: So you have a traceback in your code (a crash) and it says `NameError: name 'getall' is not defined`. This is because you've used `/getall()` instead of `./getall()` on L14

Comment: Oh yes, thank you! After I have other errors, one saying that the sofifa site does not exist:
2022-03-10 18:24:42 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://sofifa.com> (referer: None)

And another error is :
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str
But I do put /text at the end of the requests ...

Answer (score 0):

You have some typos, variable names mixup, and some other errors. here's what you can do:
change:

```
all_links = response.xpath('//html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/table').getall()
for link in all_links:
    # request recipe page
    yield scrapy.Request(url=f'https://sofifa.com/{link}', callback=self.parse_recipe)
```

to get the href of the links:

```
all_links = response.xpath(
        '//*[@id="body"]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a[1]/@href'
    ).getall()
for link in all_links:
    yield scrapy.Request(
            url=f"https://sofifa.com{link}", callback=self.parse_recipe
        )
```

You have to also fix:

```
next_page = response.xpath('//div[@class="pagination"]/a/@href')/getall()
```

and use get instead of getall:

```
next_page = response.xpath('//div[@class="pagination"]/a/@href').get()
```

You also have to rename the variables `prix` and `salaire` to `price` and `wage`

After your code will execute but it will still need some more work.